# Get the SQL column Value dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column in table A. the column name is Sequence number. The Structure of table A is numbers from 1,2,3,4.....3600.

Now on the basis of table A. I want the below output from the SQL select query for SQL server 2008.

```
seq no      dynamic col
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           1
6           2
7           2
8           2
9           2
10          2
11          2
12          3
13          3
```

My Second column is getting generated at the run time. 
And the business logic is that, if the seq number mod 6 = 0 then increment the value of dynamic column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...Actually I have thought to create a variable and then increment the value of variable inselect statment. But i am not getting the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select seqno, (seqno/6) +1  dynamiccol
from t
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edd85/1)

Comment: i also dont understand, it's not beautiful but does the job

Comment: But Now my question is what if.. My Sequence Number column contains the name as below and I want a data in below listed format.

Answer (score 1):

Take this as pseudo code because I'm not familiar with SQL Server specifically, but it should give you somewhere to go.

```
SELECT
    seq_no,
    ROUNDDOWN(seq_no/6)+1 AS dynamic_col
FROM
    my_table
```

Comment: Thanks Sir.. You saved my time. Now I can sleep well.. :D

Comment: Thats fine.. But now my question is what if my sequence Number Column contain the data in the below format and i want dynamic column as listed..                                                                       seq no  dynamic col
  
Abc  6
Axz  6
Ayc  6
Bnk  7
Bhk  7
Cxl  8
Cgh  8
Col  8
Cdf  8
Drf  9
Der  9
Dre  9
Dsal  9
Dex  9
Efg  10
     Here the logic says if the first character of sequence number column changes then increment the value by one

Comment: No it doesn't, not if that is all your data. All that says is to take the first character in the column, get it's ASCII value and perform a linear transformation to get your desired results. That alone should help, but if you need more that is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: So can you please which type of linear transformation can be performed to get the above output

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ you can use this to figure that out. Subtract some number by the ascii value of the first letter to get the dynamic column value you are looking for.